# 128 bit Integer hash function

Tags: python, mysql, hash, bigint

Looking for a string to integer hash function with values in the range of mysql `bigint unsigned` datatype (`0 <= n <= 18446744073709551615`). Converting md5/sha1 to integer with the base of 16 does not fit this requirement.

Comment: What kind of properties does your hash function need? Should it be cryptographic? Does it need to be fast? I'd expect it'd need to be consistent across different executions of a program.

Comment: @user2357112 No cryptography. The value is going to be used as integer key values for strings. Low collisions requirement is a must.

Comment: In essence you want a 64-bit hash. Wikipedia has a few that are listed as 64-bit both cryptographic and non-cryptographic, including RIPEMD-64, Siphash, elf64, etc. Why such a limited hash size though?

Comment: @ChrisJ Thank you. The hash size is limited by the mysql column datatype which is not allowed to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java uses a [rolling hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_hash) that should work for you

From `java.lang.String` :

```
public int hashCode() {
    int h = hash;
    if (h == 0 && count > 0) {
        int off = offset;
        char val[] = value;
        int len = count;

        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            h = 31*h + val[off++];
        }
        hash = h;
    }
    return h;
}
```

The idea is to calculate the hash as :

```
s[0]*31^(n-1) + s[1]*31^(n-2) + ... + s[n-1]
```

To deal with overflow, you can add a step where the hash is checked against `18446744073709551615` and if it is larger take the `mod` of the hash and `18446744073709551615`.